# Check if value already is in series

Tags: pine-script

I have a series called data created by a conditional I created that determine when to buy stocks, example:

```
data = if condicoes
    close
plotchar(data, char="B", color=color.green)
```

But In some parts of the graph there are 4-5 "B" together, how can I avoid this. Like I need to stop the script for 4-5 candles when it a new value enters data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, also it would be helpful to provide `condicoes` if you have it, what do you mean by

> 4-5 "B" together

Maybe that you want to use `show_last` in `plotchar`

```
plotchar(data, char="B", color=color.green,show_last=5)
```